# Convergence of a sequence of sets

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Given a squence of sets $\{S_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, where each $S_{n}$ is countable set. I came over this statement in some article, it says: "Let $S$ be the weak limit of $S_{n}$". But I couldn't find a good definition for weak limit of a sequence of sets.

Any one know anything about this!

Comment: Could you possible add the source from which you got that?

Comment: Sorry, I just got some notes and didn't save that article. But you can consider it as a general question about weak convergence!

Comment: Is the question then "how would you define something called the weak limit of a sequence of sets"? Well, I'm going to define it to be $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the $S_n$ are subsets of a Banach space $\cal B$.  Then one possible interpretation of "weak limit of $S_n$" would be a set $S$ such that for every finite
$\{f_1, \ldots, f_k\} \subset B^*$, $\{(f_1(s),\ldots,f_k(s)): s \in S\}$ is the limit
(in the Hausdorff metric) of $\{(f_1(s),\ldots,f_k(s)): s \in S_n\}$ as $n \to \infty$.